# Page will overflow on iphone

Tags: ios, viewport

Hi,

I have this viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=1">
```

and this page width:

```
html, body {width:100%;min-width:1180px;}
```

It looks fine on a computer screen. However, if I see it on an iPhone 4 it looks choppy on the right side. So it is necessary to scroll right in order to see the missing part. I dont want that. The whole page should fit inside the screen but it wont unless I reduce the width to 1100px or less but I need it at 1180px.

What is wrong here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to coding, but a little while ago I read an article that said you can check which iPhone the user of your app has. This way you can use an if-statement to make the width depending on the device. Maybe google a bit further on "check iOS device programmaticly"? Hope that this did help you in some way!